Code after using Pyinstaller results in Called Process Error (Tabula returns non-zero exit status)
To apologize upfront, this is my first question on stackoverflow, so I will try to be as clear and concise as I can be.
I am trying to create a Pyinstaller .EXE file from a python script I have been making the past few weeks, but I seem to run into a problem trying to run the executable after it is made. When I use VS Code to run the program, everything works great. However, once I create an .EXE for my script and virtual environment, I keep getting the error below.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TableReader.py", line 108, in <module>
    dataOut1 = tabula.read_pdf(file_path, pages = pages_input, stream=True)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "tabula\io.py", line 400, in read_pdf
  File "tabula\io.py", line 86, in _run
  File "tabula\backend.py", line 122, in call_tabula_java
  File "subprocess.py", line 571, in run
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['java', '-Dfile.encoding=UTF8', '-jar', 'C:\\Users\\mhman\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI200402\\tabula\\tabula-1.0.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar', '--pages', '15-17', '--stream', '--guess', '--format', 'JSON', 'C:\\Users\\mhman\\Downloads\\GreenvilleOfficeTower.pdf']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Here is the code for line 108.
dataOut1 = tabula.read_pdf(file_path, pages = pages_input, stream=True)

I have tried to find a solutions from other questions on here, but at least from what I found, those problems dealt more so with having issues with Tabula in people's IDE.
Here are some of the options I have tried with Pyinstaller, if that is the problem.
Pyinstaller TableReader.py --onefile --windowed 

Pyinstaller TableReader.py --onefile --windowed --name "TableReaderAlpha"

Pyinstaller TableReader.py --windowed --name "TableReaderAlpha" --collect-all tabula-py

Pyinstaller TableReader.py --onefile --windowed --name "TableReaderAlpha" --collect-all tabula-py

I saw from a somewhat similar thread that the issue could be arising from the version of Java being used. But if that was the case, why would it run in VS Code and not as the application. I thought the whole point of Pyinstaller, at least for the reason I am using it, is to create a single independent .EXE that does not need a specific system setting or dependency.
I am new to Python and using Pyinstaller, so this could be a pretty easy fix, but I just do not know what it could be with everything I have seen so far.
